# changing Set<String> values from database to string values

Tags: java, jdbc

How do i make my program read a Set value from the database one word by one word.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class SetProblem {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs  = null;

    Set<String> nums = new HashSet<>();
    nums.add("1");
    nums.add("2");
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/database/set.db");
        st = con.createStatement();
        //st.execute("create table data(word, synonyms);");
        //st.executeUpdate("insert into data values('figure', '"+nums+"');");
        rs = st.executeQuery("select * from data;");
        Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            set.add(rs.getString(2));
        }
        for(String s:set)
        {
            System.out.print(s + "");
        }
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Driver not found");
    }
    catch(SQLException s)
    {
        System.out.println("wrong sql command");
    }
}
```

}

my problem is that it prints [1, 2] instead of 
1
2 
which i want. How can i achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean "it returns [1, 2]"?

Comment: Also, your code seems to be doing several things all combined together. Since you already have a `Set<String> set`, why do you declare `TreeSet<String> tree` just to copy it? And why do you need a copy for every iteration of the `while` loop?

Comment: I meant 'print' not 'return' am sorry for the mistake

Comment: I suggest that you separate out each task into separate methods. One method can open the database connection and return a `Connection` object. Another method can execute the Query and return either a `ResultSet` or a `Set<String>` depending on which you prefer. Another method can print out the results in the `ResultSet` or `Set<String>`. Then `main()` should be a few lines of code which tie all these methods together.

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting one row, but what you want (I think) is to insert two rows. You see  [1, 2] because it is exactly what you're inserting in the second column (you're forcing a nums.toString()).

Here the code I think you were looking for:

```
    //...
    Set<String> nums = new HashSet<>();
    nums.add("1");
    nums.add("2");
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/database/set.db");
        st = con.createStatement();
        //st.execute("create table data(word, synonyms);");
        //for(String i: nums)  //HERE YOU NEED TO CYCLE
        //   st.executeUpdate("insert into data values('figure', '"+i+"');");
        rs = st.executeQuery("select * from data;");
        Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            set.add(rs.getString(2));
        }
        for(String s:set)
        {
            System.out.print(s + "");
        }
    }
    //...
```